# Determing number the query ran by core wordpress

Tags: themes, query

I wanted to find out, how many queries does wordpress core run, and how many queries the theme run. Is there any way to get they number of both of them separately ? As i run

```
`echo get_num_queries();
queries in
timer_stop(1);`
```

It gives me total of queries, but i want to have the number separate, of how many does theme run, and wordpress core alone.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Query Monitor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin for that
Not quite sure if it distinguish between both but it's a great plugin for query monitoring and debugging.

Comment: Query Monitor shows you which component of the site performed each query: core, the theme (parent/child if relevant), and each individual plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dummy theme, with just an index with static content, and check the value of `get_num_queries()` there, that way you can have an idea of how many queries the core executes, and then, do the same with the theme you want to use activated.

I don't think this approach is gonna be perfect, but it could give you a good idea of the number of queries executed.

I'm gonna expand a bit on this:

You can get the queries run (including the SQL), by setting a constant in wp-config.php:

```
define('SAVEQUERIES', true);
```

With this, what you can do is create add the following function to your functions.php:

```
add_action('shutdown', 'number_of_queries');
function number_of_queries(){
    global $wpdb;
    echo 'on PHP shutdown';
    var_dump($wpdb->queries);

}
```

The action `shutdown` executes after PHP is done executing, so if you get the queries at this point, you can get all the queries.

Also, you can call `$wpdb->queries` from diferent files, to see the queries ran by the time they are executed.

With the following function you get the queries ran by wordpress by the time the functions.php file is loaded.

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'number_of_queries_after_setup_theme');
function number_of_queries_after_setup_theme(){
    global $wpdb;
    echo 'after_setup_theme';
    var_dump($wpdb->queries);

}
```

You can check the basic execution order [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Query_Overview)

The plugin [debug bar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/) is a great option too